# Closing meld window in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, meld

In 14.04 I could close a `meld` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. But in 16.04 the behavior of that key combination has changed to terminate all currently open invocations of `meld` rather than just the one I pressed the key combination in.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, but that can only close individual tabs and the window remains open even if all tabs inside it have been closed.

Is there a keyboard combination which will close a single `meld` window in 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded Meld to 1.5.3 with the following actions:

```
sudo wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/meld/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb -O /var/cache/apt/archives/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb 
sudo apt-get install -f    

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-meld
Package: meld
Pin: version 1.5.3-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

It works better for me. It has for example very useful `<Ctrl+Shift+R>` shortcut and close with `<Ctrl+Q>`.

Comment: Installing the package that way sounds like a huge security risk. This does no validation of the integrity of the downloaded package.

Comment: @kasperd You are right, but I can't use newer version of Meld because of well-formed (shortcut) habbits and better usability of previous version :)